# Do I need to marshal IStream returned by CreateStreamOnHGlobal, for use across threads?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, com, marshalling

I have a COM stream object ([`IStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), created with [`CreateStreamOnHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I want to use it across different threads within the same process. Do I need to marshal the stream object itself (with `CoMarshalInterface` etc)? Or is it thread-safe already?

**EDITED**, reads/writes/seeks are properly synchronized with locks in my codes.

Comment: Please see my comment.

Comment: @Ben, how about [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), just found it: *Thread safety. The stream created by SHCreateMemStream is thread-safe as of Windows 8. On earlier systems, the stream is not thread-safe. **The stream created by CreateStreamOnHGlobal is thread-safe.***

Comment: oddly that's not in the documentation for CreateStreamOnHGlobal. I suspect it may be an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COM treats `IStream` as a special type of interface, which can be safely used across threads. This is necessary so that other interfaces can be marshaled across thread boundaries in an `IStream` using [`CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693316.aspx).

Additional information can be found in a 2003 article of Dr. Dobb's: [Marshaling COM interfaces](http://www.drdobbs.com/marshaling-com-interfaces/184416838).

**Update:**

The answer, as initially posted, is not entirely correct. The OLE-provided implementation of the `IStream` interface, as returned by [`CreateStreamOnHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980.aspx) and indirectly created through [`CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693316.aspx) can be safely accessed across threads in the same process.

Documentation is scattered and hard to come by. `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` states the following:

> The stream returned in the ppStm parameter is guaranteed to behave correctly when a client running in the receiving thread attempts to unmarshal the pointer.

Similar information is available for `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` from [`SHCreateMemStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831.aspx):

> The stream created by CreateStreamOnHGlobal is thread-safe.

The guarantees do not generally hold true for all `IStream` implementations. If you want to play it safe, you can always marshal interfaces across thread boundaries using `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`, even if not strictly necessary. It is [never harmful to marshal an interface pointer in this way because COM is smart enough not to marshal (or remarshal) the pointer if marshaling isn't necessary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302324.aspx). Keep in mind though that this is *marshal once - unmarshal once*. If you want to unmarshal the interface from multiple threads you can place the interface into the [Global Interface Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693781.aspx).

Comment: It looks like your answer is not correct, see the code I posted.

Comment: I stand corrected, see [the updated code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19896704/2674222) of my test case. Thank you, +1 (and I've undone my -1).

Comment: ***That is not correct.***  The `IStream` instance returned by `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` can be used by another thread, as per the documentation "The stream returned in the ppStm parameter is guaranteed to behave correctly when a client running in the receiving thread attempts to unmarshal the pointer." This is ***not the case*** with all `IStream` interfaces, it is a guarantee which ***only** exists for `CoMarshalInterthreadInterfaceInStream`.* The guarantee is not equivalent to full thread safety, either.

Comment: @Ben, the question I asked was about `CreateStreamOnHGlobal`, not about `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`. Shall I not rely upon such behavior of `CreateStreamOnHGlobal`?

Comment: @avo, the answer given here is "yes". The correct answer is "No". The answerer "IInspectable" was mislead by his misunderstanding of the documentation of `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`.

Comment: @IInspectable, I'd like to solicit more feedback before I can accept your answer. I did not expect this question to be that controversial.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Thread safety. The stream created by SHCreateMemStream is thread-safe
>   as of Windows 8. On earlier systems, the stream is not thread-safe.
>   **The stream created by CreateStreamOnHGlobal is thread-safe**.

I've got two opposite answers, so I decided to verify it. <strike>It looks like @HansPassant is right, and @IInspectable is wrong. At least, a proxy is created on another thread for the original `IStream` object.</strike>

The test case shows the following:

- Even if both threads belong to different apartments, a direct reference to `IStream` can still be used across threads. It just works.
- If both threads are MTA threads, the `IStream` from `thread` gets unmarshaled on `thread2` to exactly the same `IUnknown` pointer, no proxy.
- If `thread1` is STA, and the `thread2` is MTA, there is a proxy. But the direct reference, created on `thread`, still works on `thread2`.

Note how reads and writes are performed on `stream1` concurrently, inside tight loops from different threads. Of course, it makes very little sense, normally there are locks to synchronize reads/writes. Yet, **it proves that `IStream` object as returned by `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` is truly thread-safe.**

I am not sure if that is an official COM requirement to *any* `IStream` implementation, as [that Dr. Dobb's article](http://www.drdobbs.com/marshaling-com-interfaces/184416838) suggests - **most likely it is just specific to [`CreateStreamOnHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void TestStream()
        {
            // start thread1
            var thread1 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                // create stream1 on thread1
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream stream1;
                CreateStreamOnHGlobal(IntPtr.Zero, true, out stream1);
                IntPtr unkStream1 = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(stream1);

                // marshal stream1, to be unmarshalled on thread2
                Guid iid = typeof(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream).GUID;
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream marshallerStream;
                CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(ref iid, stream1, out marshallerStream);

                // write to stream1
                var buf1 = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
                stream1.Write(buf1, buf1.Length, IntPtr.Zero);

                // start thread2
                var thread2 = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    // read from stream1 (the direct reference) on thread2

                    var buf2 = new byte[buf1.Length];
                    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                    {
                        stream1.Seek(0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                        stream1.Read(buf2, buf2.Length, IntPtr.Zero);

                        // trule thread safe, this always works!
                        for (var j = 0; j < buf2.Length; j++)
                            Debug.Assert(buf1[j] == buf2[j]);
                    }

                    // Unmarshal and compare IUnknown pointers
                    object stream2;
                    CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(marshallerStream, ref iid, out stream2);
                    IntPtr unkStream2 = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(stream2);

                    // Bangs if thread1 is STA, works OK if thread1 is MTA
                    Debug.Assert(unkStream1 == unkStream2);

                    Marshal.Release(unkStream2);
                });

                for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    stream1.Seek(0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                    stream1.Write(buf1, buf1.Length, IntPtr.Zero);
                }

                thread2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
                thread2.Start();
                thread2.Join();

                Marshal.Release(unkStream1);
            });

            thread1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread1.Start();
            thread1.Join();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestStream();
        }

        [DllImport("ole32.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
        public static extern void CreateStreamOnHGlobal(
            IntPtr hGlobal,
            bool fDeleteOnRelease,
            [Out] out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream pStream);

        [DllImport("ole32.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
        public static extern void CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(
            [In] ref Guid riid,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object unk,
            out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream stream);

        [DllImport("ole32.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
        public static extern void CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(
            [In] System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream stream,
            [In] ref Guid riid,
            [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object unk);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your original question wasn't clear enough as there are two different thread safety issues in play here. Is IStream thread safe as in "can two threads use the same stream simultaneously with predictable results?" - the answer is no. Is IStream thread safe as in "can a stream created on one thread be used by another thread without marshalling it across" - the answer is yes. You originally seemed to be asking the second question and @IInspectable's answer was right for that.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I think I was quite specific: a stream returned by `CreateStreamOnHGlobal`, was I not? There are other implementations of `IStream` which may work without marshaling. However, now I believe **I cannot use a direct `IStream` interface pointer, returned by `CreateStreamOnHGlobal`, across different threads.** Looks like it needs marshaling.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I stand corrected, as I've updated my test case. Despite the marshaled proxy, the direct reference still works. How interesting.

Comment: @avo: Interface pointers that do not refer to a proxy but to the actual COM object only "seem" to be usable from different threads. We had such a case recently where some object A was created in the main thread yielding ptrA, and ptrA was used in a worker thread. Although this should not be allowed, there was no run-time error.<br/><br/>However, things changed drastically when object A started to use an OutProc logging server. Now the worker thread would no longer work and an Interface-marshaled-for-wrong-apartment error (sorry, I'm too lazy to look up the proper error message) was returned.

Comment: @StuartRedmann, did you actually design your object A to be thread-safe, using mutexes/critical sections/etc to protect its state from concurrent access? This does seem to be the case for the `IStream` object I'm referring to. Also, you use other COM objects (the OutProc server). While that `IStream` only uses memory, I suppose.

Comment: @Ben, I've unaccepted IInspectable's answer for now and I hope to hear some more technical opinions than me having got lucky.

Comment: @avo, "got lucky" is the technical term. Nobody guaranteed this would work. Therefore if it did, you got lucky. I would be interested to see how you verified that "reads/writes/seeks are correctly synchronized with locks". Did you step into it in a debugger and see EnterCriticalSection on every read?

Comment: @Ben, "reads/writes/seeks are correctly synchronized with locks" - in my production code they will be, it doesn't make sense otherwise, I only meant that. **My point was about using the direct interface pointer to call `IStream` methods, not about data integrity. That's what the title of my question suggests**. Now that I have this test + MSDN info, I feel comfortable about it.

Comment: @avo, it is always *possible* to call any interface from the wrong thread using a direct interface pointer. Always. The question is whether, if called from multiple threads simultaneously, the object is properly protected against data corruption. The fact that you tried it and it seemed to work doesn't answer that. In Russian Roulette, you live five times out of six. That doesn't mean it is safe.

Comment: @Ben, sure. And that exactly was my question: to use marshaling or not for this specific case. I do agree, it most likely should not be propagated to other cases, although that article made me doubt.

Comment: @avo: In fact, the object A was thread-safe, I just forgot to marshal it properly and was quite surprised that it still worked. That is, until object A started to log. As Ben said two postings above, I just got lucky (or rather unlucky, because my programming error might have shown only after the SW got shipped). It were nice if the COM runtime had some kind of "debug mode" where you will always get a proxy object instead of the direct interface pointer.

Comment: @StuartRedmann, I guess I understand your case. Object A worked thread-safe, until it started calling out an external COM object (OutProc). That was the violation of COM rules.

Comment: Not quite so. The violation happened before that, when I did not marshal the pointer to A for the worker thread. However, the COM runtime only realized this until object A tried to access the logging object in yet another apartment because this is the first time marshaling code (and thus the COM runtime) is invoked and COM has a chance to perform sanity checks.    If COM did not hand out direct interface pointers but always "proxied" interface pointers, the COM runtime would have detected my violation much earlier and even without A's logging.