# COM `IStream` interface pointer and access from different threads

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, com, marshalling

Is it an official COM requirement to *any* `IStream` implementation, that it should be thread-safe, in terms of concurrent access to `IStream` methods through the same interface pointer across threads?

I am not talking about data integrity (normally, reads/writes/seeks should be synchronized with locks anyway). The question is about the need to use COM marshaller to pass `IStream` object to a thread from different COM apartment.

This is a more general question than I asked about [`IStream` as returned by `CreateStreamOnHGlobal`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19895635/2674222), please refer there for more technical details. I'm just trying to understand this stuff better.

**EDITED**, I have found this info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Thread safety. The stream created by SHCreateMemStream is thread-safe
>   as of Windows 8. On earlier systems, the stream is not thread-safe.
>   **The stream created by CreateStreamOnHGlobal is thread-safe.**

Now I believe, the `IStream` object returned by `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` is thread-safe, **but there is NO requirement that other `IStream` implementations should follow this**.

Comment: Only slightly related, but fun to mention: For marshaling COM interfaces in-process across apartment boundaries, see [CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693316(v=vs.85).aspx) (and I do believe it is the longest-named API in all of WIN32, but that was before Vista, so it may have been succeeded).

Comment: @WhozCraig, I am aware of this API, actually using it in my test case with some interesting results: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19896704/2674222

Comment: ", reads/writes/seeks should be synchronized with locks anyway"  The whole point of marshalling is to provide those locks.

Comment: @Ben, *The whole point of marshalling is to provide those locks.* - strongly disagree. I prefer to have fine manual control over this aspect across threads. **Otherwise, [thread-safe `SHCreateMemStream` on Win8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and - I believe - thread-safe `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` would not make sense.**

Comment: @avo, disagree as much as you want. I am done here.

Comment: @WhozCraig: [`IGlobalInterfaceTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678517.aspx) is preferred over `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream()`. And the longest named Win32 API function is now [SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378422.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I never use the GIT if i'm only marshaling to one thread. I should reconsider that? And thanks for the info about the new reigning champion. I see its min supported in Windows 7, so obviously I've been out of the loop for awhile now.

Comment: @WhozCraig: `CoMarshal...` is fine for simple uses. GIT avoids the serialization that `CoMarshal...` uses when making its `IStream`. GIT also works with interfaces that hold pointers to other interfaces, whereas `CoMarshal...` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't. And the accepted answer to the other question is dead wrong. Hans Passant's answer is correct. You should delete this question because it presupposes a falsehood, namely that CreateStreamOnHGlobal returns a thread-safe IStream. It doesn't. You then ask if this is true of other IStream implementations. It isn't.

In computer programming generally, and COM in particular, objects have guarantees they give and guarantees they do not give. If you use an object in conformance with its guarantees, then it will work all the time (barring bugs). If you exceed the guarantees, it may still work most of the time, but this is no longer guaranteed.

Generally in COM, the thread-safety guarantee is given by one of the standard threading models.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx

- Apartment threaded objects can be instantiated on multiple threads, but can only be used from the particular thread they were instantiated on.
- Multi-threaded apartment objects can be instantiated in a multi-threaded apartment and can be used from any of those threads.
- "Both"-threaded objects can be instantiated in any thread, and used from any thread.

***Note:*** The threading model belongs to the **object** not the **interface**. Some objects supporting `IStream` may be single-threaded, others may be fully-thread safe. This depends on the code which implements the interface. Because an interface is just a *specification*, and thread-safety is not something covered by it.

It is always harmless to marshal an interface. If the threading models of the threads are compatible with the object's home thread, you will get the exact same interface pointer back. If they are not compatible, you will get a proxy. But it never hurts to marshal, and unless you know that the objects are compatible, you should always marshal.

However it is always open to an implementer to give additional guarantees.

In the case of `CoMarshalInterthreadInterfaceInStream`, you are told in the documentation that the returned `IStream` interface can be used for unmarshalling at the destination thread, using `CoUnmarshalInterfaceAndReleaseStream`.

That is, you have been given *an additional guarantee*. So you can rely on that working.

***But that does not apply to any other instance of `IStream` at any time.***

So you should always marshal them.

Comment: And it will still be wrong no matter how many people upvote it, and downvote this.

Comment: Consider editing your question, the part about `CreateStreamOnHGlobal`. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): *The stream created by CreateStreamOnHGlobal is thread-safe*. That's the only reason I down-voted it, otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: @avo, final comment, ***that assurance is not in the documentation for `CreateStreamOnHGlobal`***. While it is probably true, I for one would not rely on it. Instead, **marshal the pointer to the other thread**. If it is a thread safe object, you will probably get the same pointer back. But it is for the marshaller to make that decision, not you.